# Hair becoming white in one night after tremendous stress

Tags: hair, stress

You have surely heard about soldiers during the war whose hair became white in one night due to the tremendous stress.

I was wondering how is this possible biologically ?

Comment: Are there any documented medical cases of this? Without them, these stories are just hearsay. Stress does contribute to gray/white hair - just look at before and after pictures of the last 4 or 5 US presidents. However, this does not, and from a physiological perspective cannot happen overnight.

Comment: I've never heard of this phenomenon.

Comment: Seems Not at all a biological process; bcoz if it was due to solely biological effect (toxification, gene mutation etc) then only new portions of hairs would bleach. Bt since entire-hair bleached in 1 night; (as well hair is a dead structure); a biological-process-change has nothing to do on that older portion off hair. Sulphur Dioxide (SO2) has a bleaching effect. SO2 is produced from burning of gunpowders. maybe excessive smoke of gunpowder caused it; however bleach of SO2 is not persistent, so maybe some more complicated chemical reactions from warfare chemical-pollutants took place there.

Comment: @Chris Yes it is a completely a speculation and I'm transferring it as a comment. However I could not find any reference claiming change of hair color on warfare; however one of my school chemistry textbook says SO2 used in bleaching of gentle materials like wool, feather, silk etc.

Answer (score 2):

The physiological condition you are looking for is commonly called *Marie Antoinette Syndrome*.

Under extreme psychological stress, the hair of the person does turn white but not in a single night (takes place slowly over successive days; in a matter of weeks) and cases of this has been reported worldwide generally in warzones.

Contrary to what you suggest, this phenomenon is extremely rare and I doubt many soldiers experience it.

Source- http://archderm.jamanetwork.com/mobile/article.aspx?articleid=712060

Another interesting tidbit the author mentions is whether Marie Antoinette herself suffered from it or not. The author goes in depth on the topic; regardless the syndrome is definitely real with documented cases. It is also known as *canities subita*.

Most in the scientific field now refer to it as an acute episode of *diffuse alopecia areata*. Alopecia areata is patchy hair-loss. This syndrome is referred to as such because the white hair eventually fall off.

Comment: Could you add a source to that?